# How to decode an array of json objects

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have an array of json objects like so:

`[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"},{"e":"f"}]`

What is the best way to turn this into a php array?

[`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) will not handle the array part and returns `NULL` for this string.

Comment: Works fine for me. If you use json_decode($arr, true) you'll get a Associative Array. Otherwise, you'll get an array of Objects. Perhaps that is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

json_decode() does so work. The second param turns the result in to an array:

```
var_dump(json_decode('[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"},{"e":"f"}]', true));

// gives

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["a"]=>
    string(1) "b"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["c"]=>
    string(1) "d"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["e"]=>
    string(1) "f"
  }
}
```

Comment: When the second parameter is `true`, "returned objects will be converted into associative arrays"

Comment: My version (PHP 5.2.9, json 1.2.1) also properly parses the json string into an array.

Comment: Yeah my bad. The code to scrape the json from the page was flawed. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
$array = '[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"},{"e":"f"}]';
print_r(json_decode($array, true));
```

Read the manual - parameters for the `json_decode` method are clearly defined:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php