# Decode data with Json in PHP

Tags: php, json, decode

i need decode this Json with the PHP, but i dont know how. I saw this function php.net/json, but it haven't how to decode this type of data.

```
{"c":[{"v":"0","e":"","n":"45","cc":"PSDB - PTB \/ PPS \/ DEM \/ PMN \/ PSDB \/ PT do B","nm":"JOSÃ‰ SERRA","nv":"VICE: ÃNDIO DA COSTA"},{"v":"0","e":"","n":"13","cc":"PT - PRB \/ PDT \/ PT \/ PMDB \/ PTN \/ PSC \/ PR \/ PTC \/ PSB \/ PC do B","nm":"DILMA","nv":"VICE: MICHEL TEMER"}],"r":[{"f":"Oficial","dt":"30\/10\/2010","v":"1","t":"2","ht":"22:00:09","tf":"false","m":"N"}],"t":[{"vl":"0","vv":"0","e":"135804433","vnom":"0","s":"400001","c":"0","tv":"0","a":"0","vb":"0","st":"0","ea":"0","vn":"0"}]}
```

Comment: The right link was right there at the page you got to...

Comment: @Chacha  Relax. If it's repeat behaviour, I'm with you. But this is a new user who didn't find the right link, okay?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decode an array of json object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594183/how-to-decode-an-array-of-json-object)

Answer (score 5):

How 'bout `json_decode($your_string);`? Doesn't that work?

Comment: Well, for example: `$obj->{'c'}` will give you the content of c. See here for an explanation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 2):

[`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/json_decode)

```
$array = json_decode('{"c":[{"v":"0","e":"","n":"45","cc":"PSDB - PTB \/ PPS \/ DEM \/ PMN \/ PSDB \/ PT do B","nm":"JOSÃ‰ SERRA","nv":"VICE: ÃNDIO DA COSTA"},{"v":"0","e":"","n":"13","cc":"PT - PRB \/ PDT \/ PT \/ PMDB \/ PTN \/ PSC \/ PR \/ PTC \/ PSB \/ PC do B","nm":"DILMA","nv":"VICE: MICHEL TEMER"}],"r":[{"f":"Oficial","dt":"30\/10\/2010","v":"1","t":"2","ht":"22:00:09","tf":"false","m":"N"}],"t":[{"vl":"0","vv":"0","e":"135804433","vnom":"0","s":"400001","c":"0","tv":"0","a":"0","vb":"0","st":"0","ea":"0","vn":"0"}]}')

print_r($array->c["v"]);
```

Comment: I think it's actually `$array->c[0]->v` or something. Json_decode unpacks it quite weird in object mode.

Answer (score 2):

```
$before='{"c":[{"v":"0","e":"","n":"45","cc":"PSDB - PTB \/ PPS \/ DEM \/ PMN \/ PSDB \/ PT do B","nm":"JOSÃ‰ SERRA","nv":"VICE: ÃNDIO DA COSTA"},{"v":"0","e":"","n":"13","cc":"PT - PRB \/ PDT \/ PT \/ PMDB \/ PTN \/ PSC \/ PR \/ PTC \/ PSB \/ PC do B","nm":"DILMA","nv":"VICE: MICHEL TEMER"}],"r":[{"f":"Oficial","dt":"30\/10\/2010","v":"1","t":"2","ht":"22:00:09","tf":"false","m":"N"}],"t":[{"vl":"0","vv":"0","e":"135804433","vnom":"0","s":"400001","c":"0","tv":"0","a":"0","vb":"0","st":"0","ea":"0","vn":"0"}]}';

print_r(json_decode($before));
```