# How to decode some JSON into PHP

Tags: php, json, decode

I have the following JSON output from a file. How would I extract the "last" from "SLL" into a php variable?

```
{
   "USD" : {"15m" : 93.89699, "last" : 93.89699, "buy" : 93.25001, "sell" : 93.89698, "24h" : 84.3, "symbol" : "$"},
   "CNY" : {"15m" : 573.0, "last" : 573.0, "buy" : 563.76252, "sell" : 588.11678, "24h" : 572.65, "symbol" : "¥"},
   "JPY" : {"15m" : 9100.0, "last" : 9100.0, "buy" : 9100.0, "sell" : 9150.0, "24h" : 8240.81, "symbol" : "¥"},
   "SGD" : {"15m" : 115.20412, "last" : 115.20412, "buy" : 112.64417, "sell" : 117.51034, 
   "SLL" : {"15m" : 23207.99, "last" : 23207.99, "buy" : 23207.99, "sell" : 23207.99, "24h" : 23207.99, "symbol" : "L$"},  
}
```

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: take care that your JSON is valid. Yours is not, it has a trailing comma (ok in most browsers but still not allowed) that will break PHP json_decode.

Comment: characters in JSON also need to be UTF-8 encoded. You might run into trouble with your symbols if you dont do so. (example: \u012 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first look your JSON have some irregularities:

Wrong JSON:

```
{
   "USD" : {"15m" : 93.89699, "last" : 93.89699, "buy" : 93.25001, "sell" : 93.89698, "24h" : 84.3, "symbol" : "$"},
   "CNY" : {"15m" : 573.0, "last" : 573.0, "buy" : 563.76252, "sell" : 588.11678, "24h" : 572.65, "symbol" : "¥"},
   "JPY" : {"15m" : 9100.0, "last" : 9100.0, "buy" : 9100.0, "sell" : 9150.0, "24h" : 8240.81, "symbol" : "¥"},
   "SGD" : {"15m" : 115.20412, "last" : 115.20412, "buy" : 112.64417, "sell" : 117.51034, 
   "SLL" : {"15m" : 23207.99, "last" : 23207.99, "buy" : 23207.99, "sell" : 23207.99, "24h" : 23207.99, "symbol" : "L$"},  
}
```

Right JSON:

```
{
    "USD":{"15m":93.89699,"last":93.89699,"buy":93.25001,"sell":93.89698,"24h":84.3,"symbol":"$"},
    "CNY":{"15m":573,"last":573,"buy":563.76252,"sell":588.11678,"24h":572.65,"symbol":"\u00a5"},
    "JPY":{"15m":9100,"last":9100,"buy":9100,"sell":9150,"24h":8240.81,"symbol":"\u00a5"},
    "SGD":{"15m":115.20412,"last":115.20412,"buy":112.64417,"sell":117.51034},
    "SLL":{"15m":23207.99,"last":23207.99,"buy":23207.99,"sell":23207.99,"24h":23207.99,"symbol":"L$"}
}
```

}

For take last element of SLL node:

```
$arr = json_decode($json,1);
end($arr["SLL"]);
```

Comment: trailing comma is even worse (referring to original) ;)

Comment: I know, the symbols, i know. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

use this function

```
json_decode($yourJSONString);
```

http://php.net/json_decode

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/json_decode

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode the json value.

use

```
$decode = json_decode(#your json value#);
echo $decode->SLL->last;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

[How to decode an array of json objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594183/how-to-decode-an-array-of-json-objects)

Answer (score 0):

```
$jsonArr='{
   "USD" : {"15m" : 93.89699, "last" : 93.89699, "buy" : 93.25001, "sell" : 93.89698, "24h" : 84.3, "symbol" : "$"},
   "CNY" : {"15m" : 573.0, "last" : 573.0, "buy" : 563.76252, "sell" : 588.11678, "24h" : 572.65, "symbol" : "¥"},
   "JPY" : {"15m" : 9100.0, "last" : 9100.0, "buy" : 9100.0, "sell" : 9150.0, "24h" : 8240.81, "symbol" : "¥"},
   "SGD" : {"15m" : 115.20412, "last" : 115.20412, "buy" : 112.64417, "sell" : 117.51034}, 
   "SLL" : {"15m" : 23207.99, "last" : 23207.99, "buy" : 23207.99, "sell" : 23207.99, "24h" : 23207.99, "symbol" : "L$"}  
}';

print_r(json_decode($jsonArr));
```

**Output**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [USD] => stdClass Object
        (
            [15m] => 93.89699
            [last] => 93.89699
            [buy] => 93.25001
            [sell] => 93.89698
            [24h] => 84.3
            [symbol] => $
        )

    [CNY] => stdClass Object
        (
            [15m] => 573
            [last] => 573
            [buy] => 563.76252
            [sell] => 588.11678
            [24h] => 572.65
            [symbol] => ¥
        )

    [JPY] => stdClass Object
        (
            [15m] => 9100
            [last] => 9100
            [buy] => 9100
            [sell] => 9150
            [24h] => 8240.81
            [symbol] => ¥
        )

    [SGD] => stdClass Object
        (
            [15m] => 115.20412
            [last] => 115.20412
            [buy] => 112.64417
            [sell] => 117.51034
        )

    [SLL] => stdClass Object
        (
            [15m] => 23207.99
            [last] => 23207.99
            [buy] => 23207.99
            [sell] => 23207.99
            [24h] => 23207.99
            [symbol] => L$
        )

)
```

This will give you the last what you asked

```
$decodeArr = json_decode($jsonArr);

echo end($decodeArr->SLL);
```