# How to separate elements from JSON array

Tags: php, json

I am executing a **php** script and getting the following results:

```
[{"0":"1010100000100000100","nonnull_columns":"1010100000100000100"}]
```

can I extract the string quoted in second quote  i.e. `1010100000100000100`??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decode an array of json objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594183/how-to-decode-an-array-of-json-objects)

Answer (score 0):

It's an object inside an array.

```
$json_string = '[{"0":"1010100000100000100","nonnull_columns":"1010100000100000100"}]';
$json_decoded = json_decode($json_string);
$first_element = $json_decoded[0];
$nonnull_columns = $first_element->nonnull_columns;
```

Above code can of course be shortened.